# Why does \w+ match a trailing newline?

Tags: python, regex

I am curious why the following would output that there was a match:

```
import re

foo = 'test\n'
match = re.search('^\w+$', foo)

if match == None:
  print "It did not match"
else:
  print "Match!"
```

The newline is before the end of the string, yes? Why is this matching?

Comment: `$` "matches the end of the string *or just before the newline at the end of the string*"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`^` and `$` mean "start of line" and "end of line", not "start of string" and "end of string". Use `\A` for "start of string" and `\Z` for "end of string".

Comment: In Python it's `\Z` for "end of string" (different from Perl, which has `\Z` and `\z`).

Answer (score 9):

From Python's [`re`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) documentation.

> **'$'**
>   Matches the end of the string or just before the newline at the end of the string, and in MULTILINE mode also matches before a newline.  *foo* matches both ‘foo’ and ‘foobar’, while the regular expression *foo$* matches only ‘foo’. More interestingly, searching for *foo.$* in 'foo1\nfoo2\n' matches ‘foo2’ normally, but ‘foo1’ in MULTILINE mode; searching for a single *$* in 'foo\n' will find two (empty) matches: one just before the newline, and one at the end of the string.